# imageview inside uitableviewcell collapses the cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios-autolayout

This is the tabel view cell with the image view

```
class ChatTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)


        self.contentView.addSubview(userImageView)

        userImageView_constraints()

        }

        var userImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        let imageViewHeightAndWidth: CGFloat = 55
        let image = UIImage(named: "steve")
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageViewHeightAndWidth / 2
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()


func userImageView_constraints(){
    userImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    userImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    userImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55).isActive=true
    userImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55).isActive=true

}
```

and heres the code for the table view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chatCell", for: indexPath) as! ChatTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
```

And this is the error that shows in the console

[Warning] Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a table view cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead. Cell: >

Comment: Add a bottom constraint from the bottom of the image view to content view's bottom anchor.  If needed, you can give it a low priority to allow other content to effect the height

Comment: That just breaks my imageview constraint Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281e1a530 UIImageView:0x10132ca80.height == 55   (active)>

Comment: shouldnt topconstraint with height be enought for the tableview cell to calculate height

Comment: The content view needs to be resolved, so you need constraints from the top to the bottom, from that the overall height can be calculated

Comment: but its still breaking the constraint

Comment: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights), [example](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells), [example](http://www.thomashanning.com/uitableview-automatic-row-height/), [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html), [example](https://www.sitepoint.com/self-sizing-cells-uitableview-auto-layout/). Also don't forget to set `estimatedRowHeight`

Comment: *"but its still breaking the constraint"* - Did you set the bottom constraints priority lower than 1000?  I usually use 999.  Are you using `estimatedRowHeight` in the `UITableView`?

Comment: setting the priority resolved it. Thanks! those examples are very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contentView`, it's not strictly necessary, I use straight `self.addSubview()`

Since the height of your image is greater than the height of a standard row. You either have to implement a height with `UITableViewDelegate` method `heightForRow` where the height is greater than your `55` or you to add a bottom anchor: `userImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true`